# Break a file into chunks and send it as binary from client to server in C using winsock?

Tags: c, sockets, winsock

I created an application that send a text file from client to server
So far i'm send it as string like this:

```
fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        newLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), 5000, fp);
            if (newLen == 0) {
                fputs("Error reading file", stderr);
            } else {
    source[++newLen] = '\0'; /* Just to be safe. */
            }
    }else{
        printf("The file %s does not exist :(");
        return 1;
    }


    fclose(fp);

    send(s , source , strlen(source) , 0); //send file
```

However my professor told me I must send the file in Binary and be ready to accept a file of any size 
I'm trying to figure out how to send the file in binary and break it into chunks

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: If `source` is 5000 `char` long, then this `source[++newLen] = '\0'` writes past the end of the array.

Comment: You should read man strlen().  It's bad and not required since you already know how  many valid bytes have been read into the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy it one byte at a time.

Reading/writing more than a byte at a time *theoretically* would make it read and write more efficiently to disk. But since the binary is likely short, and disk I/O is already internally buffered it probably doesn't make a noticeable difference.

`perror()` is a convenient function that displays the text associated with an error code returned from the most recent UNIX system call.  The text in the quotes is the title it displays before showing you the system message associated with the code.

`exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` exits with a -1 value which is what scripts can test to see if your program succeeded or failed, as the exit status can be retrieved for a UNIX program.

`size_t` is an integer type, but it's named size_t to give a hint as to what you're using it for.

If you wanted to transfer more data at a time you could.  But 1-byte xfers is simple and safe and it works.

```
FILE *exein, *exeout;

exein = fopen("filein.exe", "rb");
if (exein == NULL) {
    /* handle error */
    perror("file open for reading");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
exeout = fopen("fileout.exe", "wb");
if (exeout == NULL) {
    /* handle error */
    perror("file open for writing");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
size_t n, m;
unsigned char buff[8192];
do {
    n = fread(buff, 1, sizeof buff, exein);
    if (n) 
        m = fwrite(buff, 1, n, exeout);
    else   
        m = 0;
} while ((n > 0) && (n == m));
if (m) 
   perror("copy");
```

Comment: can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: It's very similar to what you already have and understand. What part would you like clarification on?  I updated the text in the top to explain why I'm using 1 byte xfers.

Comment: reading by 1 byte makes HUGE difference. Problem is not in caching, but in context-switching from your process to system and back for every one byte.

Comment: @Agent_L - For a typical binary it won't make a practical difference from the user's perspective since the program will run virtually instantaneously. As far as OS performance goes and the optimal implementation, that's beyond the scope of the question, but he can increase the size of the xfer and experiment and even use dtrace and get performance metrics if he wants and even catch the system and user-mode calls made as it runs.

Comment: @MartinJames - I worked in a kernel performance tuning group. I understand that. I've tuned apps that have to scale.  But for all practical intents and purposes for illustrating a basic concept this is fine.  The context switches on a standalone single user system copying small binaries just don't matter.  Optimizing to scale up.  I'm sure whatever example you gave, someone could come along and say 'but but there's a faster or more efficient way to do it'.  How about mmap or SAN on fiber? I mean, let the punishment fit the crime.

Comment: @1sand0s I did a large scale experiment some years ago with 1700 data points that showed the single most influential factor in a TCP transfer is the socket receive buffer size, and the next is the size of individual transfers. I've never seen anybody claim that writing a single byte at at a time is efficient, in nearly 40 years in IT.

Comment: IMO It depends on the application. I worked in a performance team of a kernel group and I'm familiar with optimizing the hell out of code too. But when I'm making a tool to do something, I consider the specific application at hand, likely future applications, and the actual need, and where efficiency doesn't amount to a perceptible or at least problematic difference and there are advantages to not going to the trouble, I jut do what works.